# Carregar imagem e inserir dentro de uma DIV

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de que quando eu clicasse em CARREGAR, abra o explorer para eu escolher a **imagem** e carregue ao lado a imagem, onde há uma DIV, como acontece em vários sites.

Tem algum plugin para isso?

Comment: somente um preview?

Comment: Pode ser preview, é a primeira vez que me deparo com essa situação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há necessidade de nenhum plugin para este feitio, você pode simplesmente utilizar o elemento input do html que seria o seguinte:

```
<input type=file id=teste>
```

Você logo teria um botão para selecionar um arquivo em seu computador e poderia resgatar o caminho do arquivo da seguinte forma, em javascript:

```
$('#teste').val();
```

Logo você pode apenas setar o `src` do seu elemento `<img>` para o resultante arquivo.

```
var img = $('#teste').val();
$('#id_sua_img').attr('src', img);
```

## Obs:

Isso só funciona se for local, se você quiser que qualquer usuário carregue um arquivo de seu próprio computador para que o mesmo seja carregado em sua aplicação, aí teria de ser feito um upload para o servidor utilizando php e depois bastar utilizar o caminho destino do upload como src da imagem

Comment: Sim, com o `input type=file` eu consigo carregar o arquivo, mas eu quero mostrar a **imagem** em outra div.

Comment: Você está a usar jQuery. jQuery serve para isso. @Paulo, atualize a sua resposta utilizando `$("#sua_img").attr("src", $("#teste").val());`

Comment: @FelipeStoker se não entender a resposta comente.

Comment: Perfeito, demorei pra entender, mas compreendi agora.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu utilizo os componentes da Kendo UI, veja o exemplo deles [aqui](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/index), mas também tem exemplos na [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). Veja os dois que vai te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a classe `FileReader` para ler a dataurl da imagem e jogar na div, que nesse exemplo meu, é uma tag  `<img>`mesmo

```
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
};
```

E o código do HTML para isso:

```
<img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 75px;" />
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
```

Assim você vai ter uma preview da sua imagem.

Comment: Sim, porém é necessário destacar que desta forma a imagem não será carregada para o servidor, por isso ela não irá ser "salva" em nenhum lugar, um simples F5 na página vai fazer com que a imagem desapareça.

Comment: isso, somente uma preview, por essa causa, o melhor seria ter um botão "salvar" ou "salvar alterações" como muitos sistemas possuem.